# Now you're Packing with Portals #2: Hashtag

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction, polyomino

[image: puzzle]

Place the colored shapes into the white area, *without rotations or reflections*, so that they fill it perfectly. The gray walls don't just block shapes, though - they act as portals!

When you place a shape, it has to stay in one piece, connected as it was before. However, cells separated  by a gray wall are still connected - the shape stretches across the wall as if it had no thickness. The edge of the board also wraps around, so a piece that sticks off the right side reappears at the left, and so on.

This puzzle has only one solution. Good luck finding it!

---

Here are some examples of valid and invalid placements. This U-shaped piece can easily warp across a single gray wall:

[image: lenghty boi]

This O-shaped shape can't be placed in the same way, since that would break it:

[image: you've gone too far]

Adding another teleporter fixes this:

[image: repaired]

Comment: I'm very happy with the improved description. I thought the wording in the previous puzzle was alright, but this is undeniably clearer. (Also, the puzzle is nice!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is (each color marked as x/y/z, where X/Y/Z marks the top left cell of each piece so that you can follow the warps from there)

> ```
>   y   y
> X y z z z
>   x   x
> x x Z x z
>   Y   y
> ```

Comment: That's right! Clearly, I have to make these harder... But don't worry, I have plans ;)

Comment: @Woofmao This one definitely wasn't easy, and we all know that polyomino packing puzzles can be made arbitrarily hard :) Also, nice job with the piece design, especially the partially cut pieces which give much more freedom in warping grids.

Comment: Here's an "original art" diagram of this solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnqLZ.png

Answer (score 7):

It can be solved as follows

> [image]

With

> the letters showing the starting positions